# Sending HDD to sleep after unmounting it in server running on CentOS Linux?

Tags: backup, mount

How to send to sleep a hard drive completely after it's being unmounted?

I'm planning to have separate 4TB drive only for backups. It will be encrypted and I will only mount it when I need to perform big backups. After unmounting it again, I would like to send it to sleep, i.e. *physically to make it stop spinning*.

Is there a way to do it in CentOS Linux 6.3?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The title of the above post was different enough to throw me off, but it answers the same question.

Comment: Sorry, but I was really trying to find the answer - the titles are not really clear on the previous posts. I couldn't find it!

Comment: I did not find it either, despite looking. Only after I went back with a 'this must have been asked before' attitude I found the other post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by sending the drive a command via [hdparm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm). Either by sending it a direct command to go to sleep (`-y` or `-Y`), or by setting the timeout for the drive to  do this on its own.

The relevant commands for that are:

- `hdparm -S180 /dev/hdc` (Enter standby mode on its own after a multiple of 5 seconds. Valid values are [1..240]
- `-y` Immediately enter low power consumption standby mode, usually causing it to spin down.
- `-Y` Immediately enter the lowest power consumption sleep mode, causing it to shut down completely. **A hard reset or soft reset is required before the drive can be accessed again.**

Comment: thank you! Is there a way not to restart the server to take it out of standby mode? Once you try to load 'mount' command and refer to this standby-ed  drive, then it would automatically started spinning again?

Comment: Using -y (small letter, not the capital Y) should allow that. It is the difference between standby and sleep. In standby the disk should be useable, though it make take a while to spin back up. So your mount command may seem to hang for about half a minute.